# Which Design Pattern needs to be used in the scenario?

Tags: design-patterns

I have the following very simple scenario:
Let's say user enters a number and the expected outputs are:
1.Collection of numbers which are odd and less than entered input
2.Same as above for even numbers.
3.Same as above for magic numbers etc.
and so on..
So basically, given a number User expects series of collections based on different criteria.
May I know which design pattern will be most suitable here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am specifically looking for which Structural Design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking into `Strategy` - it's a pattern that enables an algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime.